# When using Tonic (Grpc for Rust) how to strip url path prefix?

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

I try to use grpc-web and my reverse proxy doesn't provide mechanism to strip api url prefix like '/api' from requests forwarded to backend. Is it a way to configure tonic to strip '/api' prefix from incoming request so that it can response to '/api/myapi.v1.GreetingService/Hello' same as to '/myapi.v1.GreetingService/Hello' ?

```rust
use tonic::transport::Server;
use tonic_web::GrpcWebLayer;

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "[::1]:8080".parse()?;
    Server::builder()
        .accept_http1(true)
        .layer(GrpcWebLayer::new())
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're incoming requests are prefixed (with anything). My understanding of gRPC Web is that it provides a JavaScript client that makes non-HTTP/2 requests to the proxy that invokes the methods on a backing gRPC server. It sounds as though you're trying to make HTTP|REST calls `/api/...` against the proxy, is that correct? That won't work. Your code doesn't bind your backend to any services and so needs work too.

Comment: You may want to investigate the [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) this will route REST|HTTP semantics to gRPC services.

Comment: Envoy is overkilling in my setup. I'm sure it should be a way to strip prefix from incoming http1 request and then let tonic's grpc-web do the rest.